# How do I pop a simple alert box via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here's my code in the  tag:

```
<script>
function saveQuantity(quantity) 
{
  $.ajax({

  alert(quantity);

  })
}
</script>
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<form name="frmQuantity">
 <select name="owned" id="owned" onChange="saveQuantity(this.value);">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9+">9+</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Why isn't this working? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you are writing you don't need ajax, but I guess you want to do an ajax call and on success alert.

If you only want to alert, this will do the trick:

```
<script>
function saveQuantity(quantity){
alert(quantity);
}
</script>
```

To do an ajax call and alert on success, do it like this:

```
<script>
function saveQuantity(quantity) 
{
  $.ajax({
  url:"/path/to/executing_script.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{quantity : quantity}
  success:function(data){
  alert(data);
  }

  });
}
</script>
```

You need to echo the updated quantity on the `executing_script.php` to show it in your alert

Answer (score 3):

You don't need ajax for a simple alert box. Change your script as below

```
<script>
    function saveQuantity(quantity) 
    {
        alert(quantity);
    }
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jo8bmqv2/

Answer (score 1):

Though you don't need Ajax for the same you are doing but still if you are researching then you can use it like.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://yoururl.com",
beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
alert("if you want to call alert before request put it here and can skip your URL");
}
})
.done(function( data ) {
   alert("if you find alert after success response");
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is for asynchronous HTTP request ([Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). It doesn't look like AJAX is what you need.

If you're trying to display a simple alert do this...

```
function saveQuantity(quantity) 
{
    window.alert(quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write like this it will work in ajax method

```
<script>
function saveQuantity(quantity)  
{
 var that=this;
 $.ajax({
 alert(that.quantity);

})
} 
</script>
```